# Flutter Admob Interstitial Ad overwrites system bottom navigation bar color to white

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have [admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) in my flutter app. My system bottom navigation color is set to a custom color by the following flutter code:

```
PlatformApp(
      material: (_, __) => MaterialAppData(
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        theme: ThemeData(
          splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
          applyElevationOverlayColor: true,
          accentColor: Color(0xffe22249),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
            primary: Color(0xffe22249),
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            background: Color(0xff090909),
            surface: Color(0xff090909),
            onSurface: Color(0xffffffff),
            onBackground: Color(0xffffffff),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In my page I use:

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      ),
```

Here is how I show interstitial ad:

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = InterstitialAd(

        adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
        targetingInfo: MobileAdTargetingInfo(
          testDevices: ["MY_SECRET_PHONE_ID"],
          
        ),
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) async {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
              interstitial
                  .show(
                anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
                anchorOffset: 0.0,
                horizontalCenterOffset: 0.0,
              )
                  .catchError((e) {
                //TODO: Log error to analytics
                print(e);
              });
     
          } 
        });

    interstitial.load();
```

The ad shows fine. I get the test ad.

**My problem is for some reason, whenever an ad is shown it overwrites my system bottom navigation color to white which makes it seem odd and ruins the continuity of my apps style. Here is what happens:**

[image]

As you can see the system bottom navigation is overwritten to white. This looks odd. I want to keep my apps custom color that I set with the flutter code while showing interstitial. Is this possible? Why is the system bottom navigation bar color overwritten?

Here is my manifest file:

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
     
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            >
... REST OF MANIFEST IS IRRELEVANT...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the color property of the navbar using **SystemUiOverlayStyle** like this.

```
const mySystemTheme= SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
.copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.red);
```

Use AnnotatedRegion widget on your screen where you show adds like this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
value: mySystemTheme,
child: new MyRoute(),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this, you can set margin bottom to the main layout that you set (Admob Interstitial) layout.
like this,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
          child: yourAdmobLayout(...)
```

after this your Admob widget takes margin to the bottom, and not overlapping to bottom navigation bar.

New update regarding style
Try this demo

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/akshatapp/6b6993ed7b7c10063ffb522461134d03/raw/03887b465405943ca58d4ec0d6462416d0db5de0/main.dart

Comment: Admob isn't a widget in Google official admob library, this doesn't work

Comment: Ok I got it,you have problem in interstitial add. I Update my answer for this.try this demo

Comment: Doesnt work, I didnt understand how this was supposed to fix the issue, can u eloborate?

Comment: You are facing issue in interstitial admob,so that's why I will share you demo project link.try to run this.its helpful for you

Comment: i tried running your demo but my issue still exists, the buttom nav bar is white